# $fillable в Laravel, как правильно сделать?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Помогите разобраться:

Форма регистрации. В ней стандартные поля (логин, пароль).

В таблице users:

`id name password role`

В $fillable добавил

```
name password role
```

Данные из формы отправляю в validator(), а потом в create().

```
protected function validator(array $data)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:18', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:18'],
            ]);
        }

protected function create(array $data)
        {
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                'role' => 1,
            ]);
        }
```

В данном случае может пользователь подменить данные и в role записать любое значение? (так как в $fillable я добавил role и это поле доступно для массового заполнения).

Или лучше в БД role сделать с значением по умолчанию, а из $fillable и create() удалить его?

Comment: "В данном случае может пользователь подменить данные и в role записать любое значение?" - Если не валидировать запрос, то да.

Comment: вот этого не совсем понял, я валидирую name и password. Поля Role в форме нету. В create отправляю значение для role обычное число (не беру значение из формы). Это безопасно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как пользователь подменит? Вы же передаёте захардкоженное значение.

`$fillable` даёт только то, что при вызове методов `save()`, `create()`, `update()` (и других подобных) могут изменяться только те поля, которые указаны (например, поле `id` ни под каким предлогом изменяться не может, или же у Вас есть другая логика, где поле должно быть строго статично).

Как только Вы с реквеста начнёте его принимать, только тогда нужно проверять, что Вы получаете и откуда, а до того момента нет повода для беспокойств (опять же, если Вы к своему коду не даёте всем подряд права, но в таком случае это меньшая из проблем, которая Вам грозит).

Вот этот вариант **будет опасен**:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:18', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:18'],
        //'role' => ['required', 'numeric', 'in:1'], - это обезопасит любое действие пользователя, но нет смысла давать ему такое, пока у Вас может быть только одна допустимая роль при отправке формы
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'], //Возможна подстановка любого значения, если нет проверки в валидации
    ]);
}
```

---

Вариант со значением по умолчанию в базе данных уместен, но может быть неудобен. Более того, рано или поздно Вы всё равно будете передавать не только первую роль.

Comment: Спасибо большое